# Assigning pointers in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

I was taking a peek at blogs, detailing the vulnerable code of the Heartbeat implementation of OpenSSL.

I found this line:

```
unsigned char *P = &s->s3->rrec.data[0], *p1;
```

What i do not understand is how is this pointer *p, assigned two different values?
The one is:

```
&s->s3->rrec.data[0]  (also, why is he referencing s?)
```

and the other is

```
*p1
```

How come this pointer get assigned two different values?

Comment: `p` and `p1` are two different variables. `p` is assigned a value, `p1` isn't. That's all!!!

Comment: @barakmanos Why don't you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following statement

```
unsigned char *P = &s->s3->rrec.data[0], *p1;
```

equals

```
unsigned char *P = &s->s3->rrec.data[0];
unsigned char *p1;
```

this further equals

```
unsigned char *P;
unsigned char *p1;
P = &s->s3->rrec.data[0];
```

And in C, `&s->s3->rrec.data[0]` means taking the address of `s->s3->rrec.data[0]`.

Oh, by the way, `unsigned char *P = &s->s3->rrec.data[0];` is a definition and initialization of pointer variable `P`, there is no assignment in it.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that there is no assignment going on either, since OP asks about that.